# Loading a javascript and running it on a specific controller and specific action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have standard rails app format.

I have these controller:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

end
```

and I have the file `app/assets/javascripts/static_page.js.coffee`

**I want 2 things:**

1. load this javascript **ONLY** when I am running one of the pages of the static_pages
2. be able to make different js calls depending on the specific action inside the controller:

the javascript file should look like:

```
//general javascript code
if (isThisHelpPage) {
   //Run some help page code
}

if (isThisAboutPage) {
   //Run some about page code
}
```

I assume that the first issue should be solved somehow with the `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file by adding some rule like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .

//= (isItStaticController? render static_page.js.coffee)
```

But I want to know how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't add conditionals to the application js file as it is precompiled when the app is deployed. 
There are two potential approaches that I can see working for you here:

1) Place all of your javascript in a single file as you have above then set the page in your code like this:

```
<script> page = "Help" </script> or <script> page = "About" </script>
```

your script could then become:

```
if(page === "Help") .... else if(page === "About") ....
```

2) the other option would be to create separate js files for each page, and then incorporate them via a yield :head block in your layout. In your help file it would look like this:

```
<% content_for :head %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'help' %>
<% end %>
```

I personally favour the second approach in my apps.

Comment: if you go for option 2, don't forget to change the `//= require_tree .` line accordingly in your `application.js`, otherwise your controller specific files will end up loading on every page anyways.

Comment: Thanks felix, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain how I handle this. In my `ApplicationController` I have a method that runs from a `before_filter` on  every request.

```
def prepare_common_variables
  controller_name = self.class.name.gsub(/Controller$/, '')
  if !controller_name.index('::').nil?
    namespace, controller_name = controller_name.split('::')
  end

  @default_body_classes = ["#{controller_name.underscore}_#{action_name} ".downcase.strip]
  @default_body_classes = ["#{namespace.underscore}_#{@default_body_classes.join}".strip] if !namespace.nil?
end
```

In `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` I have the following

```
<body class="<%= yield :body_classes %> <%= @default_body_classes.join(' ') %>">
```

For your `StaticPagesController`, when the `help` action runs, this would generate the following `<body>` tag:

```
<body class="static_pages_help">
```

Next, I have a method like this in my `app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb`

```
Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
  return this.filter(function(i) {return !(a.indexOf(i) > -1);});
};

var DEEFOUR = (function (deefour) {
  deefour.Utility = (function (utility) {
    utility.hasBodyClass = function() {
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
      if (args.length === 0 || $('body').get(0).attr('class') == "") return false;

      return args.diff($('body').get(0).attr('class').split(/\s/)).length == 0;
    };

    return utility;
  }(deefour.Utility || {}));

  return deefour;
}(DEEFOUR || {}));
```

Finally, in my equivalent of your `app/assets/javascripts/static_page.js.coffee` I will have something like this

```
$(function(){
  if (!DEEFOUR.Utility.hasBodyClass('static_pages_help')) return;

  // code for your help page
});

$(function(){
  if (!DEEFOUR.Utility.hasBodyClass('static_pages_about')) return;

  // code for your about page
});
```

This is nice because in your view

```
<% content_for :body_classes, :some_custom_class %>
```

or within a specific action

```
@default_body_classes << "some_other_custom_class"
```

you can conditionally add specific classes to match against in your Javascript.

```
// *both* 'static_pages_help' and 'some_other_class' are required
if (!DEEFOUR.Utility.hasBodyClass('static_pages_help') || !DEEFOUR.Utility.hasBodyClass('some_other_class')) return;
```

`hasBodyClass(...)` accepts an arbitrary # of arguments; just list them out. This is useful for things like a `new` and `create` action which you want the same Javascript to run for when a form fails to submit.

```
if (!DEEFOUR.Utility.hasBodyClass('some_controller_new', 'some_controller_create')) return;
```

It should be noted, `prepare_common_variables` needs a bit of tweaking as it only allows for a single namespace like `SomeNamespace::TheController` and not more like `SomeNamespace::AnotherNamespace::TheController`.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice here is to use the content_for helper method. Kind of like described by @Adam, but you probably want to put a `<%= yield :script_files %>` in the bottom of your layout file, and then call

```
<% content_for :script_files do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'your_js_file' %>
<% end %>
```

from within the action you want it to be. You can do this even cleaner by following a similar approach as mentioned by Ryan Bates in an early Railscast:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def javascripts(paths)
    content_for :script_files do
      javascript_include_tag(paths.is_a?(Array) ? paths.join(',') : paths)
    end
  end
end
```

You can then, from your action view, just call `<% javascripts 'your_js_file' %>` and have that file included.

Answer (score 0):

> load this javascript ONLY when I am running one of the pages of the static_pages

First of all, asset pipeline compiles and creates static asset files `offline`, meaning that you can not create bundles dynamically based on the controller name during the serving of a user request (in production).

However, you can use a separate `<%= javascript_include_tag "static_page_manifest.js" %>` statement instead of (including the `application.js`) in the corresponding layout file (of StaticPages controller) to define certain javascripts for the specific views. For example, you can have a `app/assets/javascripts/static_page_manifest.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .

//= static_page
```

Alternatively, if you want dynamic javascript module inclusion, you could use `requirejs` (`requirejs-rails`) etc.

> be able to make different js calls depending on the specific action inside the controller

This could be achieved by checking an body tag `id` with a value depending on controller and action names! For example:

```
<body id="static_pages_<%= controller.action_name %>">
...
```

And then you can check this id value in the javascript bundle to execute certain code snippets.